# we need to return correct exception to calling service when dependency service is down

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-actuator, hikaricp

We have a typical scenario,

Setup:
Mysql --> (Spring Data JPA - HikariCP + Spring Boot + Actuator) --> Eureka FW --> Clients

Problem:
if Database is down Spring boot is returning 404 not found exception. Instead of the correct exception i.e. JDBC connection exception or a spring wrapper.

Need your help in throwing the right exception to the client.

Thanks and Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: The exception is coming from Eureka Gateway. it keeps checking the health of the service every 2 Mins. once it finds that the service is not healthy. it starts returning 404 and requests are not forwarded to actual service.  But 404 is not the right exception any pointers to configure Eureka service to return an custom message will be helpful.